# Auto-complete text field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete, textfield

How do I make an autocomplete text field like the one here at Stack Overflow for the Tags fields? I want to use it for my Rails app.

Answer (score 4):

StackOverflow uses the [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), it has multiple item support.

Check the [demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/).

Snippet from the edit page:

```
$("#tagnames").autocomplete("/tags/filter", {
    max: 6,
    highlightItem: true,
    multiple: true,
    multipleSeparator: " ",
    matchContains: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Auto-Complete Text Fields in Rails 2](http://codeintensity.blogspot.com/2008/02/auto-complete-text-fields-in-rails-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is, you trigger AJAX requests to the server, using onkeydown or onkeypress events (preferably with a bit in the way of delays), that do your search using the text entered so far and send back possible completions to the client.  The client then does DOM manipulation to display these.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options you can do [Rails Jquery UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) with the [Autocomplete gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) OR [TokenInputs](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and look at the [Railscasts on TokenFields](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) on how to set it up for your situation. Personally, i like what latter does with its own personal themes.